# why $("#iframeID").contentWindow.FunctionFromIFrameNode(); is not working?

Tags: jquery, iframe

> $("#iframeID").contentWindow.FunctionFromIFrameNode();

is throwing error, but it is working when define the element index as follows

> $("#iframeID")[0].contentWindow.FunctionFromIFrameNode();

Can somebody explain the internal?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using jQuery. `$` is a factory function that returns a set of DOM elements that matches the selector passed to it (`$` can be called in other ways). jQuery defines very useful methods on this returned object. `contents()` is one of such. Even if only one element matches the selector in the document, `$` still returns an object with the value of property `0` a reference to the selected DOM element.

The returned jQuery object looks like this

```
var returnedObject = {
  0: DOM element,
  1: DOM element,
  length: 2,
  selector: "Selector passed to $",
  context: 2nd argument passed to $ or Document object
}
```

You can reference the first DOM element, for example, using 
`returnedObject[0].`

`$('#iframeID')` returns a set of DOM elements that matches the selector. The returned set is an array-like object that has index properties like arrays (`0`, `1`,....).

`$("#iframeID").contentWindow.FunctionFromIFrameNode()`

This would not work because you are trying to access a property `contentWindow` that is not defined on the set of DOM elements returned by `$`.

`$("#iframeID")[0].contentWindow.FunctionFromIFrameNode()`

This would work because you are accessing the first DOM element in the set of DOM elements returned by `$`. This DOM element has a `contentWindow` defined on it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. why would $("#iframeID") returns set of objects though there is only one element (with id "iframeID") in the DOM? secondly, is this rule applicable only for contentWindow property? if not then why $("#iframeID").contents().find("p").html() is working without specifying the index? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @afin I have tried to clarify my answer by adding some more details. `$(#iframeID").contents().find("p").html()` works because `contents()` is one of the many methods defined on the returned jQuery object